# Epoch Timestamp String to Joda Datetime using ONLY String Formatter

Tags: java, datetime, format, timestamp, epoch

Assuming I have a timestamp "1355409000003" as a String, is there a way to specify a DateTime format that parses that into a Joda DateTime?

I.e., I can parse "12/01/2012" with format "MM/dd/YYYY" and "2012-12-01 04:27" with "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm", but how can I parse "1355409000003"?

edit: not using a different constructor, assume I MUST specify a String format to parse with

Comment: There doesn't appear to be an existing formatter which accepts epoch time.  Since the ms count is the internal representation of the time stored by a `DateTime`, and since there's already a constructor which accepts a `long` and sets that field, I assume nobody has seen the need for one before now. If you really want one, I think you'll need to write it.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

Just [parse your `String` to `long`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong-java.lang.String-). No big deal.

Use *java.time* classes that supplant *Joda-Time* project.

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( 
    Long.parseLong( "1355409000003" ) 
)
```

> 2012-12-13T14:30:00.003Z

## Parse `String` to `long`

Your Question does not really make sense. If you get a string representing the count of milliseconds since epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00Z, then convert that `String` to a `long` and pass to the constructor of the Joda-Time `DateTime` type.

This was shown in [an Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29831564/642706) that was inexplicably deleted.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime( Long.parseLong( "1355409000003" ) ) ;
```

Or, personally, I would separate onto two lines.

```
long millisSinceEpoch = Long.parseLong( "1355409000003" ) ;
DateTime dt = new DateTime( millisSinceEpoch ) ;
```

You posted this Comment to that Question:

> unfortunately, the structure by which these timestamps are being consumed does not lend itself to using a different constructor - assuming I am REQUIRED to specify a string format, is there a format that parses epoch timestamps?

Again, your insistence on a constructor taking a `String` is nonsensical, as it is simple to the point of being trivial to wrap your textual number with a parsing call: `Long.parseLong( "1355409000003" )`. [Don’t make a mountain out of a molehill.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_a_mountain_out_of_a_molehill)

## java.time

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

Same approach here with *java.time* as seen above with *Joda-Time*: Parse the `String` to a `long`, and use the number to get an `Instant` object (rather than a `DateTime` object).

The *java.time* classes avoid constructors. So, instead of calling a constructor, call the static factory method [`Instant.ofEpochMilli`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochMilli-long-).

```
long millisSinceEpoch = Long.parseLong( "1355409000003" ) ;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( millisSinceEpoch ) ;
```

## Custom method

If the issue prompting your insistence is that this occurs throughout your code, and you want to avoid littering your codebase with all the extra `Long.parseLong(`, then you could make your own utility method to encapsulate this string-to-long conversion.

I am *not* recommending this as it seems like overkill. But if you insist, here is some example code.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import java.time.Instant;

public class InstantMaker
{
    static public Instant parseMillis ( String countOfMillisecondsSinceEpoch )
    {
        // TODO - Add code to test for invalid inputs, trap for exception thrown.
        long millis = Long.parseLong( countOfMillisecondsSinceEpoch );
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( millis);
        return instant;
    }

    // Constructor. Hide the default constructor as "private". We have no need for instances here.
    private InstantMaker ( )
    {
    }

    // `main` method for testing ad demonstration.
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Instant instant = InstantMaker.parseMillis( "1355409000003" );
        System.out.println( instant );
    }
}
```

If this is your concern, I suggest the real problem is relying on a count-from-epoch regardless of whether it is textual or numeric. A count-from-epoch makes date-time handling much more difficult as the values cannot be discerned by humans. This makes troubleshooting, debugging, and logging tricky and unnecessarily complicated. I would suggest refactoring your code to be passing around `Instant` instances rather than strings like `"1355409000003"`.

### ISO 8601

If you must serialize date-time values to text, use only the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. That is the primary purpose for the standard, exchanging date-time values between systems. The formats are designed to be practical and sensible, easy to parse by machine yet easy to read by humans across cultures.

The *java.time* classes use the standard ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. You can see examples of such strings above in this Answer.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).